# Чем отличается REST API от RESTful API?

Tags: api, rest, терминология

Объясните пожалуйста простым языком в чем отличия REST Api и RESTful API? В интернете абстрактно описано.

Answer (score 2):

**REST** - это аббревиатура (REpresentational State Transfer = передача самоописываемого состояния), обозначающая некоторые полезные свойства клиент-серверной архитектуры
**RESTful** - это прилагательное к слову REST

> чем отличается Rest Api и Restful Api?

ничем